# Per Vendor Device Unique Identifier, How is it and how much secure?

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

iOS 6.0 supports Unique Device Identifier per Vendor (or Publisher).

Has Apple revealed the identifier generator algorithm to the public?

Assume there are two apps (a1 and a2) from different vendors. If the app a1 gets its unique identifier by calling the API (for ex. `[UIDevice identifierForVendor]`) then on a jailbroken device, is it possible for the app a2 to know what the unique identifier for a1 is?

I mean for instance, on a jailbroken device, a2 may search a1 private directory and find the location where `device_unique_identifier` for a1 persisted and get it. Is it possible?